# Subtract two dates in SQL and get days of the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select I.Fee
From Item I
WHERE GETDATE() - I.DateCreated < 365 days
```

How can I subtract two days? Result should be days. Ex: 365 days. 500 days.. etc...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
Select I.Fee
From Item I
WHERE  DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), I.DateCreated) < 365
```

Comment: DateDiff must be handled with care.  If you care about hours, it will fail you.  11PM to 1AM is "1 day" according to DateDiff.  Do not use it if you see days as "number of 24-hour periods".

Comment: @Pxtl is there a function in SQL that considers the time as well?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Dunno how nobody noticed that the query is technically not correct. Expression in where clause always gives true as soon `DateDiff` will go negative. Please be aware copying this solution and put `GetDate` as second argument in `DateDiff`

Answer (score 8):

use `DATE_DIFF`

```
Select I.Fee
From   Item I
WHERE  DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), I.DateCreated)  < 365
```

- [DATE_DIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

EDIT:
It seems I was wrong about the performance on the code example.
The best performer is whichever snippet runs second in the posted case.
This demonstrates what I was trying to explain, and the time differences are not as dramatic:

```
----------------------------------
--  Monitor time differences
----------------------------------
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX dtIDX ON #ArbDates (MyDate)
DECLARE @Stopwatch DATETIME 
SET @Stopwatch = GETDATE()
    -- SARGABLE
    SELECT *
    FROM #ArbDates
    WHERE MyDate > DATEADD(DAY, -364, '2010-01-01')


PRINT DATEDIFF(MS, @Stopwatch, GETDATE())
SET @Stopwatch = GETDATE()
    -- NOT SARGABLE
    SELECT *
    FROM #ArbDates
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, MyDate, '2010-01-01') < 365
PRINT DATEDIFF(MS, @Stopwatch, GETDATE())
```

Excuse me for posting late and my crudely commented example, but I think it important to mention [SARG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

```
SELECT I.Fee
FROM Item I
WHERE  I.DateCreated > DATEADD(DAY, -364, GETDATE())
```

Although the temp table in the code below has no index, the performance is still enhanced by the fact that a comparison is done between an expression and a value in the table and not an expression that modifies the value in the table and a constant.
Hope this is found to be useful.

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#ArbDates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ArbDates
DECLARE @Stopwatch DATETIME 

----------------------------------
--  Build test data: 100000 rows
----------------------------------
;WITH Base10 (n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL  SELECT 1 UNION ALL  SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL  SELECT 1 UNION ALL  SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL  SELECT 1 UNION ALL  SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
)
,Base100000 (n) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Base10 T1, Base10 T3, Base10 T4, Base10 T5, Base10 T6
)
SELECT MyDate = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*3653.0+36524.0 AS DATETIME) 
INTO #ArbDates 
FROM Base100000

----------------------------------
--  Monitor time differences
----------------------------------
SET @Stopwatch = GETDATE()

    -- NOT SARGABLE
    SELECT *
    FROM #ArbDates
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, MyDate, '2010-01-01') < 365

PRINT DATEDIFF(MS, @Stopwatch, GETDATE())
SET @Stopwatch = GETDATE()

    -- SARGABLE
    SELECT *
    FROM #ArbDates
    WHERE MyDate > DATEADD(DAY, -364, '2010-01-01')

PRINT DATEDIFF(MS, @Stopwatch, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

diffdate is column name.

result:

DiffDate

23

Comment: Why adding an answer that doesn't add any information to the other answers in the post?

Comment: That´s not the answer, It doesn´t add/explain/correct etc. something to the existing asnwers

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Select I.Fee
From Item I
WHERE  (days(GETDATE()) - days(I.DateCreated) < 365)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (to_date('02-JAN-2013') - to_date('02-JAN-2012')) days_between
FROM dual
/
```

Answer (score -1):

Syntax

***DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)***

Description

DATEDIFF() returns (expr1 – expr2) expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

***@D Stanley***